# WooCommerce get_cart() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Before I updated to `WC` at 4.3.1 ,I had this code and it worked well

```
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
                    register_rest_route( 'px-module-woocommerce', '/px/cart', array(
                            'methods' => 'POST',
                            'callback' => array($this,'ajax_add_to_cart'),
                    ));
});
public function ajax_add_to_cart() {
       $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
}
```

now, `WC()->cart->get_cart()` still return

```
Call to a member function get_cart() on null
```

I also tried the global value `$woocommerce`. But, the result is still the same. Have you any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I dont have much experience in this area but would this reference assist you: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes that documentation is very useful, but describe only the `WC_Cart` class and is used through a Singleton in the main class WooCommerce. `WC()->cart` = `WC_Cart`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved including the functions which are loaded only on the front-end.

```
public function ajax_add_to_cart() {
            include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php';
            include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/class-wc-cart.php';

            if ( is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
                wc_load_cart();
            }

           $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot comparing to other solutions...!

Comment: This does not resolve the problem. still it says null